# Странное поведение background-position

Tags: html, css

Хотел сделать простенькую анимацию при наведении на блок. Думал сделать все через движение фона и не лезть никуда дальше. В общем при достаточной высоте вьюпорта `background-position` работает как мне нужно, так есть перемещает картинку за пределы блока при позиции 130%, но при блоках меньшего размера картинка вместо того что бы идти вниз уходит вверх. Я никак не могу понять почему. Я создал интерактивный пример:

https://jsfiddle.net/Telion/g3h372mx/1/

```js
setInterval(() => {
 $("#d").toggleClass("active");
}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  height: 20px;
}
body>div {
  background-image: url(https://cdn130.picsart.com/254265053013212.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 350px 350px;
  background-position: -100px 200%;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.active {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Не поскажете почему это происходит и можно ли это исправить не изменяя подход к задаче?

**Правка:** 
Наверное стоит добавить причину. При наведении на блок будет происходить что-то такое: https://jsfiddle.net/Telion/g3h372mx/3/

Comment: Почему себя так ведет, потому что стили так прописаны... Анимация вполне адекватно себя ведет... Но не понятно чего именно хотел добиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```css
body {
  height: 20px;
}
body>div {
  background-image: url(https://cdn130.picsart.com/254265053013212.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 350px 350px;
  background-position: -100px calc(100% + 100px);
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body>div:hover {
  width: 500px;
  background-size: 370px 370px;
  background-position: -80px calc(100% + 30px);
}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: Да! Это работает как нужно. Не могли бы вы обьяснить почему мой вариант работает неправильно? Я был бы очень благодарен.

Comment: @Telion Если честно, не знаю, но судя по поведению, в промежутке от 100% до 200% отступ идет с низу вверх. Это интересное и думаю полезное поведение, если учитывать, что отступ обычно работает только сверху в низ. А когда отрабатывает функция кальк, на выходе получается уже фиксированная величина и поведение остается стандартным. Но это не точно)

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего проблема в неправильном `background-position` во втором примере я поставил `background-position: -80px 290%;` и картинка стала уезжать в низ как и должна. Подберите правильный вариант позиции для анимации.

Comment: Второй пример это то как все должно работать. Это как бы идеальный вариант. Проблема в том что если уменьшить высоту того блока произойдет проблема с первого примера, которую я и хочу решить так как у пользователей определенно будет разная высота экрана.

Comment: В  разделе ответов, должен быть ответ, а не предположения...